# How do I control the positioning of an image in a div/ in CSS?

Tags: html, css, positioning, divider

I'm currently trying to teach myself HTML. Right now I am creating a website just for aesthetic purposes and I'm having trouble with the CSS/div. At the moment it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upGSx.png). Without the h1, it actually stays right by the text. My code looks like this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>


<title>Lovey Lovey</title>


<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.emoji.co.uk/files/phantom-open-emojis/symbols-phantom/12944-sparkling-heart.png" />

    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="love.css">

<style type="text/css">


body {background: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/elf1s7iKPGXks/giphy.gif") #ffb3ff right repeat; }

</style>

</head>


<body> 

<center>

<img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" > <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" > <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" > 

<br>
<br>


<div class = "header">
<img src= https://i.imgur.com/7Xjrk3X.gif alt= "Left" style= "height:75px; width:75px; float:left;"> 


 <h1>I love you!</h1>

<img src= https://i.imgur.com/CQl7GZu.gif alt= "Right" style= "float:right; height:75px; width:75px;">

</div>

<br>

<h2><i>Love you so much!</i></h2>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<img src = https://i.imgur.com/HCwaPsi.gif height="170" width="140"  />

<br>
<br>

<img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" > <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" > <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif/revision/latest?cb=20171010223602 height= "75" width= "75"> <img src= https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif height= "75" width= "75" >
```

And lastly my CSS looks like this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.header Left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

.header Right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is add wings right beside the "I love you!" while still having the text be large. I feel like I'm really missing something in the CSS, but I'm not completely sure. I appreciate any input you guys might have!

Comment: As you are still learning HTML I would recommend to use CSS for spacing instead of multiple `br` tags. This will result in a more readable HTML file. Also the `title` tag should go within the `head` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could give both imgs and ID like so:

```
<img src="..." id="left-wing" />
<img src="..." id="right-wing" />
```

And for css:

```
img#left-wing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 40vh;
}

img#right-wing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 60vh;
}
```

I am not sure if these dimensions will work, but play around and you'll put them where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to Css

```
  img#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45vh;
    left: 110vh;
           }
   img#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45vh;
    left: 60vh;
}
```

And Add Id's to HTML inside

```
<img id="right">
<img id="left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image attached below. If this is the way you want your html page to be, then the following steps will be helpful

[image]

Just change your code like this:

```
<div class = "header">
<img src= https://i.imgur.com/7Xjrk3X.gif style= "height:75px; 
width:75px; float:left;"> 


<img src= https://i.imgur.com/CQl7GZu.gif  style= "float:right; 
height:75px; width:75px;">

</div>

<br>

<h1>I Love You</h1>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<h2><i>Love You So Much</i></h2>
```

---

Also remove 'header h1' style from css part

Answer (score 0):

h1 being a block level element it occupies the whole viewport width. Below CSS will definitely help you with least edits:

```
.header h1 {display:inline-block;}
```

Also remove floats for wings `left` and `right` both.

Another way is adding this CSS:

```
.header { display:table; }
.header *{ display:table-cell; }
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the clutter in your HTML as suggested in my comment.

```css
body {
  background: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/elf1s7iKPGXks/giphy.gif") #ffb3ff right repeat;
  text-align: center;
}

.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
}

header,
footer {
  background-image: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/animal-jam-clans-1/images/a/a3/Tumblr_static_971v84xme8g888gwwow800cc0.gif');
  background-size: 75px 75px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Lovey Lovey</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.emoji.co.uk/files/phantom-open-emojis/symbols-phantom/12944-sparkling-heart.png" />
  </head>


  <body>

    <header></header>

    <main>
      <img src=https://i.imgur.com/7Xjrk3X.gif alt="Left" class="left">

      <h1>I love you!</h1>

      <img src=https://i.imgur.com/CQl7GZu.gif alt="Right" class="right">

      <h2>Love you so much!</h2>

      <img src=https://i.imgur.com/HCwaPsi.gif height="170" width="140" />
    </main>

    <footer></footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

I only haven't positioned the footer in this example, so that would be something you could do for yourself. Its now just as you had it in your question, but would imagine you would like to have it at the bottom of the viewport.